# Lambda expression in Python doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, lambda

I tried to make some lambda expressions. There is no any error. But it doesn't work correctly. Following is my code.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

list1 = 'gain, archive, win, success'.split(',')
list2 = 'miss, loss, gone, give up'.split(',')

def classify(s, rls):
for (f, emotion) in rls:
  if f(s):
     return emotion
return "another"

rules = [(lambda x: (i for i, j in zip(word_tokenize(x),list2) if i == j) != [], "sad"),
         (lambda x: (a for a, b in zip(word_tokenize(x),list1) if a == b) != [], "happy"),]

print classify("I win the game", rules)
print classify("I miss you", rules)
```

The output is

```
sad
sad
```

I have no idea what is the wrong with my code. Can someone help me !

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [mcve].

Comment: we also need the `word_tokenize` function definition

Comment: First, correct your code indention !!

Comment: Yes, there are many bugs in your code. Your `lambda` functions *always return `True`*, for one thing... Also, I'm not really sure `zip` is what you want. But you need to specify. But certainly, realize that `(i for i, j in zip(word_tokenize(x),list2) if i == j) != []` *is always `True` since a generator is never equal to an empty list*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zip iterates through the lists "*in parallel*", so it returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence. ([source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip))

So you were trying to check if the i-th word of the sentence matches the i-th sentiment word in the least, which I guess is not what you want. Plus, as noted by @juanpa.arrivillaga, you were checking if a *generator* was equal to the empty *list*, which is always `True`, for the simple reason that a generator is not a list, independently from its content.
What you want is checking if any word in the sentence is in the sentiment list.

Try changing:

```
lambda x: (i for i, j in zip(word_tokenize(x),list2) if i == j) != []
```

to:

```
lambda x: any(word in list2 for word in word_tokenize(x))
```

So overall you define rules like this:

```
rules = [(lambda x: any(word in list2 for word in word_tokenize(x)), "sad"),
         (lambda x: any(word in list1 for word in word_tokenize(x)), "happy")]
```

Also, there are white spaces in the words in sentiment lists that can make the comparison fail.
Redefine them as follows:

```
list1 = 'gain,archive,win,success'.split(',')
list2 = 'miss,loss,gone,give up'.split(',')
```

Or even better use [strip](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm) to remove empty spaces from beginning and end of words as general good practice when working with strings.

Comment: They are currently checking if some generator is not equal to an empty list, which is always `True`

Comment: Yes I want to check if any word in the sentence is in the sentiment list. I tried from your way. But then out put is another, another

Comment: Yes I did. Now output is happy,happy.

Comment: And you should change list2 to list1 in the second rule. What I reported was just an example for the first case.

Comment: Is this a correct way to define lambda expressions, actually this is the first time that I use Lambda expressions. Please help me,

Comment: lambda x: any(x in list1 for x in word_tokenize(x))!=[], "happy"),
lambda x: any(x in list2 for x in word_tokenize(x))!=[], "sad")  this is my new expressions

Comment: I made the answer more explicit. With 'any' you check if there is at least one match, so no need to compare with empty list.

Comment: Thank you. I solved the issue by going through your answer.